# Delayed echo of sin - cannot reproduce Tensorflow result in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am experimenting with LSTMs in Keras with little to no luck. At some moment I decided to scale back to the most basic problems in order finally achieve some positive result.
However, even with simplest problems I find that Keras is unable to converge while the implementation of the same problem in Tensorflow gives stable result.

I am unwilling to just switch to Tensorflow without understanding why Keras keeps diverging on any problem I attempt.

My problem is a many-to-many sequence prediction of delayed sin echo, example below:[image: signal_n_prediction]
Blue line is a network input sequence, red dotted line is an expected output.
The experiment was inspired by this [repo](https://github.com/sunsided/tensorflow-lstm-sin/) and workable Tensorflow solution was also created from it too.
The relevant excerpts from the my code are below, and full version of my minimal reproducible example is available [here](https://gist.github.com/wf34/fb60fc889f3eae9a674fb4e6d68c7389).

Keras model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_hidden,
               input_shape=(n_steps, n_input),
               return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(n_input, activation='linear')))
model.compile(loss=custom_loss,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate),
              metrics=[])
```

Tensorflow model:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps])

weights = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_steps], seed = SEED))
}
biases = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_steps], seed = SEED))
}
lstm = rnn.LSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm, inputs=x,
                                    dtype=tf.float32,
                                    time_major=False)

h = tf.transpose(outputs, [1, 0, 2])
pred = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(h[-1], weights['out']), biases['out'])
individual_losses = tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(pred, y),
                                  reduction_indices=1)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(individual_losses)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate) \
  .minimize(loss)
```

I claim that other parts of code (`data_generation`, `training`) are completely identical. But learning progress with Keras stalls early and yields unsatisfactory predictions.  Graphs of `logloss` for both libraries and example predictions are attached below:

Logloss for Tensorflow-trained model:
[image: tensorflow_logloss]

Logloss for Keras-trained model:
[image]
It's not easy to read from graph, but Tensorflow reaches `target_loss=0.15` and stops early after about 10k batches. But Keras uses up all 13k batches reaching `loss` about only `1.5`. In a separate experiment where Keras was running for 100k batches it went no further stalling around `1.0`.

Figures below contain: black line - model input signal, green dotted line - ground truth output, red line - acquired model output.

Predictions of Tensorflow-trained model:
[image: predictions_tensorflow]
Predictions of Keras-trained model:
[image]
Thank you for suggestions and insights, dear colleagues!

Comment: Can you try to fit a `keras` model using a `fit` method? I guess this is causing your problem as using `train_on_batch` keeps your network hidden states from a previous batch.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Sorry, but your suggestion contradicts the official documentation. LSTMs in keras said to wipe hidden states after each sample unless are constructed with `stateful=True`, which is not the case for me. That is exactly as in Tensorflow code, where states are also not preserved by default.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko After some thought, I decided it's not fair to just waive off your comment, so I investigated Keras code, didn't find any calls to `reset_states` under the hood. So I decided to add explicit call to `reset_states` after each `train_on_batch`. That haven't changed the results, though...

Comment: This is super weird than as Tensorflow resets states after each batch. Try also reset states before predicting on batch

Comment: I recently trained such a model to predict sins, including a sin x sin. I found that I had to make three training seasons to reach a nice convergence. The first season used `Adam(lr=0.001)`, the second `Adam(lr=0.0001)` and the third `Adam(lr=0.00001)`. -- Also, once I inspected the keras code for RNNs, and it seems to take care of its own weights, as if keras had its own implementation, independent from tensorflow (I may be wrong, but it really seemed like that).

Comment: Maybe the keras implementation for `LSTM` is not equivalent to tensorflow's `dynamic_rnn`.

Comment: @DanielMöller I agree. Keras indeed has its own LSTM implementation (two, actually). But I cannot believe that such a mainstream lib has an dysfunctional implementation. As I said, it does not converge on anything for me. I will try & comment on what you proposed with several different seasons. A while back I tried just one Adam with `lr decay`, it was no good also. But I'll attempt anyway.

Comment: Maybe worse than tensorflow, but it does converge, though.... how about trying a `tanh` activation at the `Dense` layer?

Comment: @DanielMöller Ok, that is reasonable too.

Comment: @DanielMöller Sadly, both suggestions didn't work out. You said, you did similar experiments recently. Is the code shareable?

Comment: Yes, it is... do you know a place where I could share it? (My company blocks lots of stuff, including "gist.github".) - I have a windows jupyter notebook with code and results.

Comment: I noticed a "custom_loss" in your keras code, although the tensorflow code seems tu use a regular "square error". Have you tried "mse" on keras?

Comment: @DanielMöller Regading the code share - is pastebin available for you? I was suspicious that keras averages along both dimesions, while TF sums along timestamps and averages along batch entries, so I wrote custom loss to get loss values similar to TF case. So, you haven't seen github gist with my code, too? I can upload it to pastebin also.

Comment: I'm currently updating my notebook.... I was getting good results with my "echo" shifted by only one step. That was easy to converge. Now I'm trying a 7-step shift, and it's way harder. I had to use much more cells, and my code is still running after 20000 epochs, and descending....

Comment: @wf34, here is the notebook (uploaded at home): https://github.com/danmoller/TestRepo/blob/master/TestBookLSTM.ipynb -- there are two kinds of predictions at the end: one predicting from the predicted elements themselvess (for future prediction) and another predicting from actual data (just to predict a shift/echo).

Comment: The last version I uploaded took actually few epochs to converge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have managed to solve this. Keras implementation now converges steadily to a sensible solution too:
[image: keras_new_training_loss]
[image: keras_new_inference_example]

The models were in fact not identical. You may inspect with extra caution the `Tensorflow` model version from the question and verify for yourself that actual `Keras` equivalent is listed below, and isn't what stated in the question:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_hidden,
               input_shape=(n_steps, n_input),
               return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(n_steps, input_shape=(n_hidden,), activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss=custom_loss,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate),
              metrics=[])
```

I will elaborate. Workable solution here uses that last column of size `n_hidden` spat out by LSTM as an intermediate activation then fed to the `Dense` layer.
So, in a way, the actual prediction here is made by the regular perceptron.

One extra take away note - source of mistake in the original `Keras` solution is already evident from the inference examples attached to question.  We see there that earlier timestamps fail utterly, while later timestamps are near perfect. These earlier timestamps correspond to the states of LSTM when it were just initialized on new window and clueless of context.

Comment: @DanielMöller I've tried yours approach with stacking LSTMs instead of using Dense layer in the end. Maybe my problem is a bit harder, because I expect the net to generalize to new unknown frequencies. It probably boils down to what I state in this answer - earlier timestamps of LSTM output always constain some gibberish. It seems you can't do without perceptron here.